# How to put whereis result into cd?

Tags: bash, shell, cd-command

My format is `whereis directory | cd` but I get no output (not even a warning).

Where as you have other posts that require variables, my question asks how to do it without them.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  The way I'm reading this is you would like to lookup the location of a directory and then change to it?  As far as I know the whereis command is for finding file sources and man pages and I don't believe it has the ability to search for directories.

Comment: whereis can be used to find a directory, what I am trying to do is output the location into cd. @Jesse_b

Comment: How do you use it to find a dir?

Comment: for example, 'whereis bin' outputs '/usr/local/bin'

Comment: That doesn't work for me on BSD.

Comment: I am running ubuntu

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: No problem.  My concern is that it's not going to work if you are searching for a directory with a field separator in the name.

Comment: hmmm, it doesn't. It outputs bash: cd: token:: No such file or directory.

Comment: What are you searching for?

Comment: Some user defined directories, but I guess whereis is not meant for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63293/discussion-between-jesse-b-and-death-by-ch0colate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So on CentOS the whereis command prefixes the output with your search.

```
[root@JBCLAMP001 ~]# whereis bin
bin: /usr/local/bin
```

So I came up with the following that seems to work in my testing so far:

```
cd $(whereis bin | awk '{print $2}')
```

Some directories will have multiple locations which may or may not be an issue.  For example on my machine the `rpm` directory has 4 locations.  The above cd command still works but it will cd you to the first listed location and not inform you that there are more.